How to find an element if the text contains &nbsp;?
I have several totals on the page among which I need to get the one that contains 2.5
<div class="cell--NEHKQ _align-left--Yc_tL">Total&nbsp;1.5</div>
<div class="cell--NEHKQ _align-left--Yc_tL">Total&nbsp;2.5</div>

I tried using the following code
//div[contains(.,'Total') and contains(.,'2.5')]

But it finds a huge number of elements on the page not related to the element I need.
Is there a simple solution to find text that contains &nbsp;?

Simple solution
//div[contains(text(), 'Total') and contains(text(), '2.5')]


NB this would also match a <div>Total: 12.5</div>

I'm afraid your question is really rather imprecise.
To find an element whose immediate text content includes a non-breaking space, the correct XPath expression is //*[contains(., '§')] where § is the non-breaking space character. How you express this character in readable form depends on the host language. If you're in XSLT, you could write it as //*[contains(., '&#xa0;')]. If you're in Javascript, you could write it as //*[contains(., '\u00A0')]. For other languages, check the rules for writing and escaping string literals in your chosen language.
Your title says you want to find a string containing an NBSP character, but the narrative of your question suggests that you are actually looking for a string "Total§2.5" where again § is my way of writing the NPSP character. Again you can substitute &#xa0; or \00A0 depending on your host language. But you also need to be careful about the word "contains". If you want to find an element whose string content is exactly equal to some string, use the XPath = operator. If you want to find an element that contains a particular substring, use the contains() function.

//div[contains(.,'Total&#20;2.5')]


I don't think &#20; is a non-breaking space. It should be &#160;.

//div[contains(.,'Total�2.5')]
and
//div[contains(.,'Total 2.5')]
Dont work for me(

If you're using XPath 2.0+, you can use matches() to use a regular expression...
//div[matches(.,'^Total&#160;2\.5$')]

If you're stuck with XPath 1.0, you can use concat() to do an exact match (so you don't match something like Total 2.51)...
//div[concat('|',.,'|')='|Total&#160;2.5|']


Thx, but it Don't work(

@EthicalHacking - Maybe your input is slightly different. What happens if you replace . with normalize-space()? (Like: //div[concat('|',normalize-space(),'|')='|Total&#160;2.5|'])

Dont' worked(((

@EthicalHacking - Something must be different with your input. The only other thing I can think of is a default namespace. Try this: //*[local-name()='div'][concat('|',normalize-space(),'|')='|Total&#160;2.5|']

There are a couple of issues here, I think.

One is the question of how to encode a non-breaking space in your XPath expression. As Michael has pointed out, this depends on your host language (i.e. the language in which your XPath expression is embedded/encoded). Note that the &#160; syntax is not XPath syntax: it is as an XML idiom for encoding a character by its Unicode codepoint. If your XPath expression is hosted in an XML-based language (such as e.g. XSLT), that &#160; will have already been converted into the actual " " character before the XPath interpreter parses the expression. But if your host language is not XML-based, then the expression &#160; will be passed to the XPath interpreter as a literal string of 6 characters (&, #, 1, 6, 0, ;), which is obviously not going to work. If you tell us what your host language is, someone will be able to tell you how to encode a non-breaking space in it. It's very likely, though, that your host language will allow you to embed a non-breaking space as a character literal without any special encoding, e.g. like this: " " (NB that is a non-breaking space, not a space " "), as many programming languages these days use Unicode as their character set. The disadvantage of that would be that the non-breaking space would look just a regular space, in your own source code, though you could of course comment it to make it clear it's a non-breaking space. Alternatively, in XPath 2.0 or later, you could use the function codepoints-to-string() to convert the Unicode codepoint 160 to a single-character string, although because you haven't mentioned what version of XPath you're using, my guess is it's probably version 1.0, which doesn't include the codepoints-to-string() function.
Secondly, there's the question of whether to use the contains() function to search for your string. When you pass your <div> element to the contains() function, the XPath interpreter first converts it to a string value. For an element, this string value is just the concatenation of all the text node descendants of the element. This would mean your query could match a <div> which contains most of the page, including, deeply nested within it, the text you are looking for. From the examples you gave, it looks like what you actually want are just the <div> elements which contain a single text node whose string value is exactly equal to "Total 2.5". This would be expressed with the expression //div[text()='Total 2.5'].

